# How to convert jars to a maven respository

Tags: maven, javapos

I am developing an application with JavaPos inclusive. The problem I have is that I am using maven but the hardware manufacturer's libs are all in jars and xml file. How do I bundle them as a maven dependency and use them in my maven project.

Any good idea is welcome so long as it helps me get this done quickly. Help really needed.

Comment: Why don’t you upload them to your repository?

Answer (score 2):

**Add external jars to local .m2 (for local development)**

This approach is not distributable. It assumes just putting jars to local .m2 and nothing more.

For adding jars to local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version>
```

*`<path-to-file>`* - is path to jar

**Create a new maven repo and distribute it within a project**

This approach assumes creating a new maven repository, which will include only external jars. Then this repository placed to the project root, added to git and referented by the project pom.

So anyone, who will download the project will have all maven dependencies in place without extra actions.

Adding jar to the new maven repo:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file:./.m2/repository/ -DrepositoryId=project-internal -DupdateReleaseInfo=true
```

Then reference the repo in your pom:

```
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
        <id>project-internal</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/.m2/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

---

**Reference**

https://www.google.com/amp/s/roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/amp/

Comment: So much hustle with JavaPos, Javafx on jdk 11 combination on maven I had to revert to ant on this project since time is of critital importance here. Thanks a lot for your response, I really appreciate that.