# How to add a maven dependency locally in android project?

Tags: android, flutter, maven, gradle, dependencies

I am integrating with Samknows library. Access to their gradle dependency is password protected, hence, I want to add this library locally in the project so, i don't need this password anymore.

I am able to locate the jar and pom file of the dependency. I tried to add this jar in the project as library but seems to not work, as POM file attach to it has all the dependency.

I am not able to figure out how to add these dependence files locally in my project. Any suggestions or approach will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630607/5226491